# Tiny micro switch identification

Tags: switches, identification

Anyone know what these switches are. More importantly where I can find a replacement. As you can see one is smashed.

They are 4mm wide by 2mm by 2mm.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please see [What topics can I ask about here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - particularly the "where to buy" bit.

Comment: You have already identified it.  Sourcing or picking a part number, which are off topic here, are accomplished by going to a vendor website that will let you search or at least sort by size.

Comment: @Srosam Sometimes ebay is a good place to find stuff like this and all you need to know is the model number of your product, and a little bit of searching effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some of these

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/pushbutton-switches/199?k=button&k=&pkeyword=button&pv235=14&sf=1&FV=1140160%2C1f140000%2Cffe000c7%2C4080030&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Sorted by button, active, instock, surface mount right angle, gull wing, and OFF-MOM.